# sharepoint SPFarm.local.GetObject return null

Tags: sharepoint

I installed sharepoint foundation 2010  (in 'Standalone' type) on windows 2012 r2.

And I created a windows app project. 
When Load , New Counter(farm) is success.

But, SPFarm.local.GetObject return null;

Does someone konw the reason,please help me.

source like this:

```
//-------source start-------

//Counter.cs
using System;

using System.Collections.Generic;

using System.Linq;

using System.Text;

using Microsoft.SharePoint;

using Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration;

namespace WinAppTest
{  

    class Counter : SPPersistedObject
    {        
         public static String SettingName = "Counter";

         public static String SettingGuid = "62648e50-8aee-42b2-b074-2f49ced85587";

         [Persisted]

         public String name;

         [Persisted]   

         public String count;   

         public Counter() 

         {

         }    

         public Counter(SPPersistedObject parent)

         : base(SettingName, parent, new Guid(SettingGuid))

         {

         }

    }

}
```

// Form1.cs

```
using System;

using System.Collections.Generic;

using System.ComponentModel;

using System.Data;

using System.Drawing;

using System.Linq;

using System.Text;

using System.Windows.Forms;

using Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration;

namespace WinAppTest
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Write_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {     
            SPFarm farm = SPFarm.Local;
            //------- *conf is null*-----
            Counter conf = (Counter)farm.GetObject(new Guid(Counter.SettingGuid));
            //------- *conf is null*-----
            conf.Name = "pf1";
            conf.count = "1";
            conf.Update();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SPFarm farm = SPFarm.Local;
            Counter conf = (Counter)farm.GetObject(new Guid(Counter.SettingGuid));
            if (conf == null)
            {
                conf = new Counter(farm);
            }
            //------- *conf is null*-----
            conf = (Counter)farm.GetObject(new Guid(Counter.SettingGuid));
            //------- *conf is null*-----

            String name = conf.name;
            String count = conf.count;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally , I think the source has error in it.

modify like this, It's OK.

```
private void Write_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {     
            SPFarm farm = SPFarm.Local;

            Counter conf = (Counter)farm.GetObject(new Guid(Counter.SettingGuid));


            if (conf == null)
            {
                conf = new Counter(farm);
            }
            conf.Name = "pf1";
            conf.count = "1";
            conf.Update();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SPFarm farm = SPFarm.Local;
            Counter conf = (Counter)farm.GetObject(new Guid(Counter.SettingGuid));

            String name = conf.name;
            String count = conf.count;
        }
```